# Inserting title block when making print templates

Tags: print-composer, qgis-print-layouts, print-templates

I am creating a print template for some figures for a report.

These figures will need a title block with all my company's details. Typically when I use it in surfer it is just a bunch of lines surrounding the image.

How would I insert a title block into the print composer? Or will I just have to make one from scratch.

Comment: Will simple graphic satisfy your request? You can try using `'Add Image'` in `'Print Composer'`